# I need creative advice for getting my Desire HD to work again

Tags: android

Here's the idea. I have a HTC Desire HD phone, rooted, custom rom (JellyTime 4.2.2) installed. This is the second time this has happened:
After a phone restart, phone gets stuck when loading on splash screen. I see the animation, then it stops, but splash screen stays for infinity amount of time. Last time this has happened I had android debugging on, I used android-sdk for `adb reboot recovery`. And got it working again, but this time I wasn't cautious, and I don't have the debugging enabled. You might ask **Why not go into recovery mode using power+volume combination? Well, I can't. My volume - button is broken.** So here I am, with a stuck phone, with no apparent way to reach recovery mode. Any suggestions, guys? I'd be grateful.

**EDIT:** I was asked to define broken. The button IS missing, but even without being missing, the bottom button simply doesn't react when you click it mechanically.

Comment: Define broken. Most volume buttons rely on a pin/button relay so you may be able to stick a pin in where the volume button was to get it to work if by broken you mean gone. If it just doesn't register a click that is obviously a different story.

Comment: @zgc7009 I defined it. It's funny how you offered two examples, yet both of those apply.

Comment: Ouch, so it is broken broken. The problem is that even if you get into the settings I think you need the volume buttons to navigation the menu.

Comment: No, I can navigate using touch buttons, or using volume + cause menu overlaps.

Comment: Holding power + back will get you to the fast boot bootloader, but I think you need the volume buttons to navigate the menu.

Comment: This worked. Thank you, guy! Post an actual answer and you'll get some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By holding the volume up I was able to get to fastboot, and then I entered my recovery mode.